# Regex match word that may or may not have prefix and suffix

Tags: javascript, regex

These are the inputs I have:

```
ab_something#123
something else#15
zy_s0meth1ng third
nothing
```

The output I need is:

```
something
something else
s0meth1ng third
nothing
```

The closest I got was this `(?:.._|^)(.*)(?:#[0-9]*|$)` but this still captures the suffix.

Comment: So it is relative to the specific word? Like `something` word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^(.{2}_)?([^#]+)(.\d+)*$/`

A friend of mine ended up helping me.

Basically:

`(.{2}_)?` matches prefix which appears 0 or 1 times

`([^#]+)` matches the middle part until #

`(.\d+)*$` matches # and all the numbers after it

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^(?:.*_)*(.*?)(?:#[0-9]*)*$`

Based on a regex tester I used, this pattern captures the desired string in group 1 for your four examples.

Things I changed:

1. Moved the start and end anchors outside the non-capturing groups to
   ensure they are always matched.
2. Used `*` on both prefix/suffix
   patterns in case there are multiple prefix/suffixes in a string.
3. Used the lazy quantifier (`*?`) on the middle pattern to ensure that
   it won't grab suffixes before the suffix group can get them.

Comment: Make sure you use \`ticks\` around things like regex. Otherwise your stars are taken to mean *italic*.

Comment: As a note on your actual answer, (?:.*_)* is going to be slow because of all the recursion. `.*_` will do the exact same thing because `.` matches `_` and `*` is greedy.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. But a friend of mine managed to solve it. `/^(.{2}_)*([^#]+)(.\d+)*$/` this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var str = ["ab_something#123",
  "something else#15",
  "zy_s0meth1ng third",
  "nothing"
];


for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  str[i] = str[i].replace(/(^[a-zA-Z]+_|#[0-9]+$)/g, '');
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Already found the solution but this also works. I like the other solution better tho because it captures prefix in a group which I also need.